# Java Jersey RESTful web service using https

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, https, jersey

I am new to Java EE and I am developing a RESTful API in which every API call the user sends encoded credentials. My problem is how to implement https protocol over default http and make my connection secure. I am using Jersey restful web services and Glassfish web server.

Answer (score 2):

That's more a setup/configuration question, isn't it? You use HTTPS (TLS) because you set it up in your server, then your REST endpoint will be used/changed accordingly...and the (encoded) credentials can be sent as usually, whether the connection is encrypted or not.

**UPDATE:**

Since you didn't specify the Glassfish version, I'll assume you are using a "recent" version. Have a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/gkyba.html) article.

Comment: Actually it is, and that is the problem. As far as I know i need to make changes in Glassfish backend setup, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for reply

Comment: I think when you start it, you can look at the default TLS port used by the container

Comment: Any tips on how to do that. I am using NetBeans. As far as I know I am only able to go to admin panel whitin this adress http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf