# Using only HTTPS in jax-rs jersey web services

Tags: https, jersey, jax-rs

I implemented several jax-rs services using jersey. Now I want them to work using ONLY HTTPS scheme. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Jersey RESTful web service using https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637450/java-jersey-restful-web-service-using-https)

Comment: The is container-level details. Read the documentation of the container you're using.

Comment: What if my services are part of vaadin web application that use simple http?

Comment: Like Peesillet said, this is a container level detail. Which container are you using? E.g. tomcat, weblogic, etc.